# How do you printSchema in Databricks without truncation of output?

Tags: schema, databricks

df.printSchema() in Databricks has its output truncated by the notebook cell. (The cell is not expandable/scrollable to see the schema in its entirety)

Is there a builtin way to view all of the schema?

For context: Python notebook, 7.4ML RunTime

[Screenshot showing truncated output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Is34.png)

Comment: works just fine for me. The output window is scrollable...

Comment: Thanks @AlexOtt Doesn't help me fix, but it's useful to know that others are seeing different ("correct") behaviours. (Also prompted me to add DBr RT details for context).